# How do I deal with the Rotten Vale?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In the Rotten Vale, there are ares of the map that drain your health, and if you stay there too long, cuts your entire health bar in half.

I know you can eat a nullberry to correct the health bar cutting, but is there a way I can eliminate the health drain altogether? During exploration/expeditions it's not much of a problem, but during hunts it's really annoying.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firing a Torch Pod at the ground will burn up the noxious gas, called effluvium, in a small area. Note, however, that only *one* area can be clear of effluvium at a time, firing a second Torch Pod will make the effluvium return around the first Torch Pod.

Alternatively, the armor skill Effluvial Expert makes you completely immune to the effects of the effluvium. It is found on the Hornetaur Mail and the Girros Coil.

For a temporary solution, wearing any mantle will stop the negative effects of the effluvium, presumably by filtering the air you're breathing.

Do note, however, that the effluvium itself *does not* cause the status effect that halves your maximum health. This status is inflicted by small monsters (Girros and Barnos) that are tainted by the effluvium, as signified by the rotten aura surrounding them.

Answer (score -4):

Do not confuse the *white/grey effluvium* emitted by Vaal Hazak with the *brown effluvium* on the bottom floor of Rotten Vale. While both slowly drains your health, the former one (Vaal Hazak's) can stack with itself and the latter, and cannot be burnt by Torch Pods. Only the former can cause a status effect which cuts maximum health bar in half.

The status effect can be removed by consuming a nullberry. It can also be completely prevented by 3rd level skill *Effluvia Resistance* (found in Vaal Hazak armor, Miasma Jewels, or Miasma Charm, note it's different from *Effluvial Expert*). If you have not defeated Vaal Hazak or do not have the Miasma Jewels yet, you can put down a Cleanser Booster and remove the status by running into the blue spray. Weapons with Elderseal can reduce the amount of effluvium on Vaal Hazak's body (not the environment), which in turn makes close combat players less vulnerable to the status effect.

Since Vaal Hazak's effluvium can stack with itself, repeated moves from Vaal Hazak can make the health drain lethal, espeically during extended encounters. This can be countered by baiting it to another area or retreating.

Comment: This question is not asking about Vaal Hazak at all.

Comment: Effluvium from the Rotten Vale cannot cause the status effect or cut max HP, thus cannot be corrected by eating nullberries as OP said.

Comment: The environmental hazard can absolutely cause the status effect. Vaal Hazak is not relevant at all.

Comment: Neither my experience nor online info recall the hazard cutting health bar in half though.

Comment: if you stay in the "rotten" vale for too long it most definitely cuts your health bar, I had this issue long before meeting hazaak(that's why the question doesn't mention him). Additionally, the rules are mostly  the same when he is around.

Comment: I'd like to remind reviewers that this is an attempt at an answer.  It is likely wrong, but it's still a good faith attempt.  We shouldn't be deleting these types of answers unless they cause harm or don't provide any information not encompassed in existing answers.  Downvotes are for incorrect answers, not recommending deletion.

Comment: @Frank It's also information that is completely irrelevant to the question. By that definition, it's not an answer.